# ClassCastException in serializerFactor for java 1.7

Tags: java

When I am moving from jdk 1.5 code to jdk 1.7, I am getting a ClassCastException in the else block of the `SerializerFactory` class.
Can anyone help me with this?

```
synchronized (key) { 
    if (this.firstCall()) { [enter image description here][1]
        _call.setEncodingStyle(null); 
        int i = 0; 
        while (i < this.cachedSerFactories.size()) { 
            Class df; 
            Class sf;                       
            Class cls = (Class)this.cachedSerClasses.get(i); 
            QName qName = (QName)this.cachedSerQNames.get(i); 
            Object x = this.cachedSerFactories.get(i); 
            if (x instanceof Class) { 
                sf = (Class) this.cachedSerFactories.get(i); 
                df = (Class)this.cachedDeserFactories.get(i); 
             _call.registerTypeMapping(cls, qName, sf, df, false); 

            } else if (x instanceof javax.xml.rpc.encoding.SerializerFactory) {                               
                sf = (SerializerFactory)this.cachedSerFactories.get(i); 
                df = (DeserializerFactory)this.cachedDeserFactories.get(i);
                _call.registerTypeMapping(cls, qName, (SerializerFactory)sf,(DeserializerFactory)df, false);
            } 
            ++i; 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Add imports, the exact error line and the full trace.

Comment: I am getting error in these line in the else part                                         sf = (SerializerFactory)this.cachedSerFactories.get(i); 
 df = (DeserializerFactory)this.cachedDeserFactories.get(i); _call.registerTypeMapping(cls, qName, (SerializerFactory)sf,(DeserializerFactory)df, false);
            }

Comment: update question based on comment and add proper grammar

Answer (score 0):

You are doing an `instanceof` check with `javax.xml.rpc.encoding.SerializerFactory` but then cast it to `SerializerFactory`, which may not be the same at all (it depends on what you imported).